# outer join, sum function with group by function

Tags: sql

I have two tables
idno

```
idno      head     head_desc
1         6001-1     medical expense
2         6001-2     pay
3         6001-3     gas expenses
```

view9

```
head       receipt    payment
6001-1      5000      1000
6001-2      7000      2000
6001-1      6000      1000
```

query

```
select i.head, i.head_desc, nvl(sum(v.receipt)-sum(v.payment),0) balance
where
v.head=i.head(+)
group by i.head,i.head_desc
```

this query should retrieve all heads in idno table and shows 0 balance if the record not found as outer join. but output is against it.

Comment: well, you don't have a `FROM` and also are using a very old deprecated way of joining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what kind of DBMS you use... But I guess you are using Oracle. 
I recommend you not to use (+) operator because it's not a standard way to express join operation.

I guess you wanted to print out every row in idno table, and if there is no v.head that has a value in idno table(for example 6001-3), then print 0(null) as a balance value. Is it right?
Left Outer Join means "print out information of every row in the left side table.
So if you want to print every i.head and i.head_desc, then you have to write
i.head = v.head(+).

Anyway I recommend you to use LEFT OUTER JOIN keyword.

Answer (score 0):

## Query:

```
SELECT idno.head, head_desc, COALESCE(SUM(receipt)-SUM(payment),0) AS balance
FROM idno LEFT OUTER JOIN view9 ON idno.head=view9.head
GROUP BY idno.head, head_desc
```